# Relative error with bands plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, dataset, error-propagation

[image]I have 2 sets of data imported from excel file, Let say
A = 20
21
22
...
30A
B= 0
1
2
3
...
10
I want to plot A with a relative error of 10%

```
errordataA= Around[A,Scaled[.1]]
```

But output was "Around[A, Scaled[0.1]]" not "Around[2+-10%]".

Then I want to create a plot with B.

```
ListPlot[
 {A,
  B
    }
   IntervalMarkers -> "Bands",
 Sequence[PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
  PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.15]}]
 ]
```

Since the code can't read set A data so the graph does not show.
How can I fix this one?

Comment: `Around` is not defined as a function in your system (it is in blue in your screenshot). Note that `Around` was introduced in version 12 (2019). What version are you using?

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @MarcoB Now I can use "Around". Just updated to M12. Thanks all

Comment: @m_goldberg it was M10 and now I already updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Around` expression you mention seems to work fine for me:

```
a = Around[Range[20, 30], Scaled[0.1]]

(* Out: {Around[20., 2.], Around[21., 2.1], Around[22., 2.2], 
         Around[23., 2.3], Around[24., 2.4], Around[25., 2.5], 
         Around[26., 2.6], Around[27., 2.7], 
         Around[28., 2.8], Around[29., 2.9], 
         Around[30., 3.]} *)
```

From there, I *think* you might want to plot `a` vs. `b`, i.e. the a values as ordinates and the values as abscissae. If that's what you want, then that works too, but you will want to `Transpose` the `{b, a}` set of data:

```
a = Around[Range[20, 30], Scaled[0.1]]
b = Range[0, 10]

ListPlot[
  Transpose@{b, a},
  IntervalMarkers -> "Bands",
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
  PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.15]}
]
```

[image: plot with error bands]

—-

An alternative interpretation after OP’s comments:

```
ListPlot[
  {a, b},
  IntervalMarkers -> "Bands",
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
  PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.15]}
]
```

[image: data as two separate series]

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your comment. I added the picture above. I have no idea why I could not get output like yours. 2ndly, I want to plot {x,A,x,B} not {A,B}. I guess I can plot it directly if I can get A in terms of the digit.

Comment: @user8357568 What do you mean by `x` in your example?

Comment: X is y axis. just give some random numbers.

Comment: @user8357568 I see. I’ve added a second output. See if that’s what you meant.

Comment: @MacroB Regarding your advice, it works great. I have one more question. How can I plot with 
Transpose[x,a], Transpose [x,b]
and a is a = Around[Range[20, 30], Scaled[0.1]]
b is b = Range[0, 10]
x = Range[0,1]

Answer (score 1):

For versions prior to v12

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"] // Quiet

a = {1, 0.1} # & /@ Range[20, 30];

b = Range[0, 10];

ErrorListPlot[{a, b},
 PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.1]},
 PlotLegends -> {"a", "b"},
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]